# Using NewWindow2 event and trying to display new form modally

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

I have a browser control on my vb form, implementing the NewWindow2 event to catch a new window request and send it to another instance of my form, per this MS article: [How To Use the WebBrowser Control NewWindow2 Event](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184876)

This is working fine when the new form is displayed non-modal.  But the browser control doesn't load up when the form is displayed modal.

Code example: create a new project, add a command button and browser control to the form.  Add the following code.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "www.microsoft.com"
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow2(ppDisp As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim ofrm As Form1
  Set ofrm = New Form1
  ofrm.WebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = True
  Set ppDisp = ofrm.WebBrowser1.Object
  ofrm.Show 'vbModal
End Sub
```

Run the project, click the command button and the web site will display.  Shift-click a hyperlink (or right-click and select 'open in new window') and a new instance of Form1 will load and the clicked hyperlink-ed site will display.

But run with the 'vbmodal' uncommented and after the new Form1 displays, the browser control isn't loaded with the new web site.

How can I get this to run displaying the new form as modal?

Thanks

**Edit**

My own fault!  The NewWindow2 event needs to complete before the new browser window will be able to display the site contents.  Since showing the form modal *in the event handler* won't complete the event handler until the form is unloaded, of course the browser control stays empty!

Per the suggestion by Noseratio, performing a modal form display essentially asynchronously is called for.  In VB6-land, using a timer makes this easy to do.

To the code example above, also add a timer control to the form, making sure that it's initially not enabled, then use the below code instead:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "www.microsoft.com"
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow2(ppDisp As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim ofrm As Form1
  Set ofrm = New Form1
  ofrm.WebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = True
  Set ppDisp = ofrm.WebBrowser1.Object
  Timer1.Interval = 50
  Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  Timer1.Enabled = False
  ofrm.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try showing the form asynchronously:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow2(ppDisp As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim ofrm As Form1
  Set ofrm = New Form1
  ofrm.WebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = True
  Set ppDisp = ofrm.WebBrowser1.Object

  Private Sub goModal()
      ofrm.Show vbModal      
  End Sub

  SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(AddressOf goModal, Nothing)  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Using an asynchronous display is indeed a/the solution.  Only thing here is your suggested code is .NET while my question was strictly vb6 based, so I'm not sure I'm comfortable with accepting your answer as-is.  If you're willing to update your answer, at least to remove the .NET-ness to it, I'd love to mark this as accepted.  Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkL, I indeed overlooked the vb6 tag, sorry. You'd use a `PostMessage` for this in VB6 (instead of `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post`, with a custom message (you could use `RegisterWindowMessage`) and pass the state information (like `ofrm`) via `lParam`. My VB is too rusty to provide a complete source code example of this.